# How does autowiring know what class to pass?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, interface, dependency-properties

I made dependency injection with LoggerInterface like :

```
// src/Service/MessageGenerator.php
namespace App\Service;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getHappyMessage(): string
    {
        $this->logger->info('About to find a happy message!');
        // ...
    }
}
```

And when I instantiate MessageGenerator in controller somehow $logger variable is passed, if it would be

```
public function __construct(Logger $logger)
```

and not

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
```

it would be obvious that it should instantiate the `Logger` class object, but how does it do with `LoggerInterface` , which class does it pass if there are multiple classes that implements `LoggerInterface`

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

LoggerInterface is the key in Symfony container which points to particular class in this container. You can see which keys matches classes using command `php bin/console debug:autowiring`
More clarifications here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services

Comment: But what If when I run `php bin/console debug:autowiring LoggerInterface`, I get information that logger key is autowired to `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface (logger)` only, and not to any class?

Comment: bin/console debug:container LoggerInterface will reveal the desired class mapping information.

Comment: @Cerad yeah it does give me `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface (logger)` information, does that mean there are no Classes passed to logger autowiring, and it should return an error?

Comment: Use debug:container not debug:autowire.  Out of the box, a monolog logger will be used.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake